# Issues setting up MapProxy to download tiles from an ArcGIS REST Service

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, rest, mapproxy

I am trying to set up MapProxy to download the tiles from an ArcGIS REST service. My yaml configuration is the following:

```
services:
  demo:
    wms:
      md:
        title: "ArcGIS REST Service"
        abstract: "ArcGIS REST Service for map tiles"
      restful: true
      layer: "arcgis_tiles"

layers:
  - name: "arcgis_tiles"
    title: "ArcGIS Tiles"
    sources: ['arcgis_cache']

caches:
  arcgis_cache:
    sources: ['arcgis_source']
    grids: ['arcgis_grid']

sources:
  arcgis_source:
    type: tile
    url: "https://sqarcgis03.ad.net.fr.ch/arcgis/rest/services/Raster/Fond_de_carte_planRF_mapproxy/MapServer/"

grids:
  arcgis_grid:
    base: GLOBAL_GEODETIC
    srs: EPSG:2056
    origin: ul
    tile_size: [256, 256]
    extent: [550654.5421999991, 152875.00030000135, 3057000, 1413000]  # BBox für den Kanton Fribourg in EPSG:2056-Koordinaten
    bbox_srs: EPSG:2056
    bbox: [550654.5421999991, 152875.00030000135, 3057000, 1413000]
    res:
      - 264.5838625010584
      - 198.43789687579377
      - 132.2919312505292
      - 66.1459656252646
      - 26.458386250105836
      - 13.229193125052918
      - 6.614596562526459
      - 4.6302175937685215
      - 2.6458386250105836
      - 1.3229193125052918
      - 0.5291677250021167
      - 0.26458386250105836
      - 0.13229193125052918
      - 0.05291677250021167
      - 0.026458386250105836
      - 0.013229193125052918
```

There seems to be an error somewhere, as all I see on MapProxy side is the following:

[image]

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `WMS` configuration should be right under the `services` section, in you case there is an extra indentation putting it under `demo`.

Your `services` section should look like this:

```
services:
  demo:
  wms:
    md:
      title: "ArcGIS REST Service"
      abstract: "ArcGIS REST Service for map tiles"
```